# Jenkins can't find latest release

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nexus

I am creating a test nexus to back our test instance of jenkins. We have a couple of artifacts that were uploaded manually in our main nexus, so I uploaded those same artifacts (using curl) to the test nexus. However our test instance of jenkins can not seem to find these artifacts when doing a build. The only difference I noticed between the main nexus artifacts and the test nexus artifacts is that the main nexus includes maven-metadata.xml, and when I uploaded these same artifacts to the test nexus there was no maven-metadata.xml created.

Do I manually need to create this? Or did I upload these artifacts incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marco, what if you solve it differently. Instead of uploading manually the dependencies to the test nexus, why don't you configure the test nexus with a remote repository pointing to the main  nexus. Then Jenkins should manage it well pointing to test nexus, transparently

Comment: This is a good solution, not the one I went with though. I uploaded it through the UI, and the metadata was created. So the root of my problem was how I was uploading it. However since I am not going to publish release artifacts with the test nexus, this solution would have been simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The Maven metadata is maintained by the uploading tool - e.g. Maven. If you do a manual upload and use the REST API it should update it. If thats not working you should kick off a scheduled task to repair the metadata after the upload.